# Bitmap Image URI, Setting an image uri with an assembly path but returns exception

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm binding the URI to a string:

```
<Image>
    <Image.Source>
        <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding ItemValue}" />
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

And in return this path is returned:

```
<ResourceValue>pack://application:,,,AssemblyOutput;component/Resources/HelloThere.PNG</ResourceValue>
```

The folder name is `AssemblyOutput > Resources > HelloThere.png`, thus the correct path is there, but it throws an exception that the file was not found.

Comment: Sorry it meant to say > HelloThere.PNG Sorry

Comment: XAMLParseExcemption... just tells me it cannot be found